# Emberjs doesn't give jQuery a handle if the tag is generated from tagName

Tags: jquery, ember.js

The picture should be a bit left, `$(this)` is empty. I suspect it's because of the missing template, I generate the HTML via `tagName`. Is there a way to solve this without using a template?

http://jsfiddle.net/T4NJh/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're trying to change the position before the element has been created. This happens because the RunLoop batches together property changes and triggers them before rendering. In this case, I would add a `didInsertElement` function which also calls the update method. See http://jsfiddle.net/wagenet/T4NJh/6/.